# Is there a hotkey for adding quotes to Python dictionary in VS Code?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Copied "Query String Parameters" from Chrome Dev Tools, and it was like:

```
param = {
    type: 24
    interval_id: 100:90
    action:
    start: 60
    limit: 20
}
```

To make it works correctly as dictionary in Python, I have to add comma and quotes like this:

```
param = {
    'type': '24',
    'interval_id': '100:90',
    'action':'',
    'start': '60',
    'limit': '20',
}
```

Is there a hotkey to adding quotes automatically?

Comment: bro, this is a good opportunity for you, to develop your own extension for VSCode

Comment: place a Multi Cursor on every line and then create a `multi-command` key/command  sequence that selects parts and types `'` to surround it. And attach this command sequence to a hot-key